# Updating location view after enabling GPS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have used an action sheet button for enabling GPS. After pressing that button, I need a updating location screen to show for some time so the user knows that it's loading. Please, can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [location manager tutorial](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/405-how-to-implement-core-location-in-an-iphone-app/)

Comment: Please don't mind but have you read the question thoroughly ? I guess his/her need is to keep user updated about loading process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the details of Delegate Methods of CLLocationManager like

> - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{}

You can use [UIActivityIndicator Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) available to keep user updated about loading process. And For having ready sample about loading process please visit [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/use-activityindicator-in-iphone/).

If you need further help please leave a comment.